# bemustached versus mustached

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word, dictionaries, word-formation

I’ve just read an [article in *The Huffington Post*](http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/6963986) in which the phrase “bemustached 26-year-old” was used:

> Sex and sword swallowing beg some pretty obvious comparisons, but the similarities aren’t as clear-cut as you might think, at least according to professional sword swallower Brett Loudermilk.
>
> The flowing-haired, **bemustached** 26-year-old sat down with HuffPost Weird News to chat about this history of sword swallowing, making a living as a sideshow performer, and exactly how you get something so long and hard down your throat.

While I’m very much aware of the function of the prefix *be‑* in words like *bespectacled*, *bejeweled*, and *bedimpled*, I can’t find the word *bemustached* in Merriam-Webster. *Mustached*, on the other hand, is entered in the dictionary.

**Question**: Would you say “mustached 26-year-old” or “bemustached 26-year-old”? Isn’t *bemustached* rather tongue-in-cheek? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I thought 'mustachioed' was the accepted wording. 'mustached' sounds like a better reasonable new word. 'bemustached' is being silly, following 'bespoke' a recently rejuvenated word.

Comment: My instinct was "mustachioed" also - I wonder if this is still used...

Comment: In general be- verbs can be traced back through Germanic roots to a thing prepared to be and now completely in a state. Over the years their meaning has often drifted and it's now not semantically separable. Like @Mitch said, the writer is being silly.

Comment: Louel, please perform an online search of the word and see if you still have a question. Also, your question is not clear: "Would you use ...?" could be asking for a range of personal preferences/subjective opinions, or possibly whether it's a standard, recognized word.

Comment: But isn't mustachio a very large mustache? Maybe being mustached/bemustached doesn't have to imply his mustache is humongous. @Oldbag

Comment: @JimReynolds: How clear did you want it to be? I indicated that I found "bemustached" in an article by HuffPost, stated that it doesn't appear in any of the readily available dictionary, and am asking people about the usage. Of course I want the subjective opinions of the people here! Usage is subjective.

Comment: 'mustachioed' does sound sort of old-fashioned, like a 19th c Sears catalog. 'mustached' sounds new to me but if any language change is desirable, I wish we'd move on to 'mustached'. Did I mention that 'bemustached' is just silly?

Comment: I wouldn't say tongue in cheek, but "bemustached" does imply something akin to "hipness", which was likely the intent of the writer.

Comment: @DanSheppard Looking for *be‑* verbs like *bemuse, beseech, behead* is a red herring here because [the *‑ed* suffix being used to create an adjective is the one used with nouns](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/233935) not the one used with verbs.  There is no verb *bespectacle* or *bejeweled* — or *bemustache*.  It’s like with studded snow tires: nobody studded them; they just have studs on them. Similarly here.

Comment: @tchrist - Actually, it used to be quite common to add studs to a tire in the tire shop, rather in the factory.  The tires came from the factory with indentations where a stud could be inserted, and a sort of "gun" was used to insert them.

Comment: @tchrist Agreed. As I said the author is being silly. But those kinds of be- verbs are, I think, clearly the reference intended by the author in the humour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are right that this word was meant to draw attention to itself.  It amuses.  The entire article is quite tongue-in-cheek — or even sword-in-cheek.  Or perhaps even something-else-in-cheek, given how it  starts and ends:

> **Sex and sword swallowing** beg some pretty obvious comparisons . . . and exactly how **you get something so long and hard down your throat**.

Those bookends set a clear tone here.  We know what is being suggested.

No dictionary contains all words — nor ever shall nor can.  There are many, many different reasons for this.  You probably didn’t find *flowing-haired* in a dictionary either.  But because it is created using a productive suffix, everyone knows what it means.

There is no verb involved here, neither *to flowing hair* not *to mustache*.  [The *‑ed* suffix](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/-ed) can turn both verbs and nouns into adjectives. Think of it as two difference suffixes.  This is not a past participle.

Obviously *bemustached* is an English word, since it was used in English and everyone recognizes what it means.  Everyone would similarly know what a *bepimpled* teen-aged face is, even if you cannot find that word in this or that dictionary.

The construction *be-* + XXX + *‑ed* is a productive way to create new adjectives in English.   According to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/be-), sense 5 of the *be‑* prefix is:

> (Forming adjectives ending in *‑ed*) having; covered with: *bejewelled*

So the fellow “has” a mustache, or even is covered with one.

The Dictionary has a lot of these *be**XXX**ed* words, but not all coinages are befated to be found in a dictionary.  Since this construction is productive, anybody can produce new ones of these whenever they please. It might catch the reader’s eye, or the listener’s ear, but this is not a bad thing. Surely this is what the article’s author intended.

Here are some from the OED:

- beblubbered
- becalmed
- beclogged
- beclouded
- becrossed
- becurled
- bedabbled
- bedangled
- bedarkened
- bedaubed
- bedazed
- bedazzled
- bedecked
- bedevilled
- bedimmed
- bedizened
- bedogged
- bedraggled
- bedressed
- bedusted
- bedwarfed
- befeathered
- befogged
- befooled
- befringed
- befrogged
- begilded
- begirdled
- begodded
- begored
- begrimed
- begrudged
- beguarded
- beguiled
- behanged
- bejaded
- bejewelled
- belaced
- belauded
- beleaguered
- belighted
- beliked
- bemangled
- bemasked
- bemazed
- bemired
- bemocked
- bemoistened
- bemudded
- bemuddled
- bemuffled
- benighted
- benumbed
- bepatched
- bepearled
- bepitched
- beplastered
- beplumed
- bepowdered
- bepraised
- bepuffed
- bepuzzled
- besainted
- bescattered
- bescrawled
- bescribbled
- beshadowed
- besilvered
- beslaved
- beslavered
- besmeared
- besmirched
- besmoked
- besmottered
- besmutted
- besnowed
- besoiled
- bespangled
- bespattered
- bespeckled
- bespectacled
- bespelled
- besplashed
- bespotted
- besprinkled
- bestained
- bestarred
- bestormed
- bestreaked
- bestriped
- bestudded
- betailed
- betasselled
- betattered
- bethumbed
- bethumped
- betimbered
- betitled
- betoiled
- betossed
- betrampled
- bewandered
- beweltered
- bewigged
- bewrapped

Comment: I am left bewildered and bemused by many of these befuddled concoctions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m especially intrigued by *bedwarfed* (perhaps from an invasion of dwarves) and *befrogged* (perhaps from a Biblical plague).  Can one also therefore be  *betrolled* and *belocusted*?  Pretty sure one could. :)

Comment: +1 But I'm slightly disappointed that you don't know what _befrogged_ means. It's not spanghewing towards a jacket although that might work.

Comment: @Frank But surely the idea that a Biblical plague of frogs raining down upon someone has somehow made them “befrogged” is a more amusing interpretation than the common sense, don’t you think? :)

Comment: The 'frognado' as it were, would indeed bedwarf the toggle makers art.

Comment: Nice list. For myself the only ones one here that are recognizable as words are: 
becalmed, 
bedazzled,
bedecked,
begrudged,
bejewelled,
beleaguered,
benighted,
besmirched,
bespectacled. Where is 'befuddled'? And the currently ubiquitous 'bespoke'?

Comment: @Mitch *Bespoke* doesn’t end in *-ed*. It is also a normal word meaning “custom” in the UK — **and always has been!**

Comment: Oh, re -ed. But then we'd want all 'be-past participle' examples. 'bespoke is totally new to me in the past couple years in AmE.

Comment: @Mitch Nouns that have *-ed* added to them are not past participles.

Comment: Sure, many of those be-X words start from nouns. Also, many come from verbs, and that's what I was referring to, not the production from nouns. 'bespoke' is another pattern, be-past participle, that could produce lots more 'be-X' words.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a joke on the once common "bewhiskered". It is funnier if you are aware that "bewhiskered" does not only have a literal meaning, but can mean old, out of date, hoary. Note that it's a 26-year-old that's "bemustached".

Answer (score 1):

The English prefix *be-* was of course once productive; in some related languages such as German it still is to some extent. As the existence of the word *bespectacled* shows, the time when *be-* became unproductive in English wasn't even so long ago. As a result, when you treat it as productive today you will still be understood; you will also get an archaic and/or comical effect.

In addition, non-native speakers and excessive readers of old literature may have the mistaken impression that *be-* is still productive, or if they don't, might decide to treat it as if it were -- as an idiosyncrasy.

Comment: No: *be-* is still productive.  There are simply too many examples of *be**XXX**ed* to forbid creating more of them by analogy.

Comment: Please define *excessive* as in “excessive readers”.  Then please defined *old* as in “old literature”. :)  Could you please point to a date after which productivity became forbidden?

Comment: I do personally believe that be-Xed *is* dated, quaint, and harks back to a more "begenteeled" society. (*begenteeled*, a word that does not exist, nor ever will but it should) :)

Comment: @tchrist: So you wouldn't say the use of "bemustached" here was tongue-in-cheek?

Comment: @Louel Not sure why you conclude that I would say such a thing from my posting.  It was a stylistic choice.  About anatomy I prefer not to speculate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think you just existed *begenteeled*. :)

Comment: @tchrist It wasn't a conclusion but a question. I'd like to know why someone would favor the use of "bemustached" over "mustached". I feel that the writer was somehow being ironic. But that's just me.

Comment: @Louel I think you have the right of it.  You seem to have a good feel for English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What do you think? Did the writer deliberately choose "bemustached" over "mustached" for humorous effect?

Comment: Anyway, here are the actual words used: Sex and sword swallowing beg some pretty obvious comparisons, but the similarities aren't as clear-cut as you might think, at least according to professional sword swallower Brett Loudermilk.

The flowing-haired, bemustached 26-year-old sat down with HuffPost Weird News to chat about this history of sword swallowing, making a living as a sideshow performer, and exactly how you get something so long and hard down your throat. http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/29/sex-naked-sword-swallower-brett-loudermilk_n_6963986.html

Comment: @Louel Yes. The fellow in question seems to wear a Salvador Dalisque moustache. A very old fashioned style.

Comment: @tchrist: I have no precise answers to your questions because the rules of grammar are statistical, not absolute. (Otherwise language wouldn't be changing all the time.) I guess it took centuries of slowly moving out of fashion for *be-* to become unproductive. But I think there is no reasonable doubt that it can be called unproductive nowadays.